# How to display location on custom map?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am using just image of map(custom map) not mkmapview control. So how can I display user's location on that image or my custom map ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add an icon, representing your location on the top of your image.

Comment: Where should I place this Icon. How to get x and y from lat and long.

Comment: Well man, this is mathematics, if you have a picture of the map, 320x480 just find the place you want to put it, there is no any method to work like that. Just use MKMapView it is very easy.